# Access VBA Macro to run pass through query

Tags: ms-access, vba, pass-through

I have a pass through query built in `Teradata` set to export data to an Excel spreadsheet. I'm trying to automate it, but when I run the macro or open the query, a window pops up asking for the data source. I have an ODBC connection created and I'm thinking there has to be a way to make the macro pass the data source name so it will run without interaction.

[image]

**Edit: Adding Macro as requested**

```
Function AutoExec()
On Error GoTo AutoExec_Err

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Performance Interval Data", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", _
"filepath\filename.xlsx", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.Quit acExit    

AutoExec_Exit:
    Exit Function

AutoExec_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume AutoExec_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: Have you set your connection string in the ODBC query? You can google for DSN-less connection strings

Comment: Would you kindly post the macro you're trying to run?

Comment: Function AutoExec()
On Error GoTo AutoExec_Err

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Performance Interval Data", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "filepath\filename.xlsx", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.Quit acExit


AutoExec_Exit:
    Exit Function

AutoExec_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume AutoExec_Exit

End Function

Answer (score 0):

Couple of concerns, (can't validate any of this right now as I do not currently have access to Access for testing), but it looks like:

1. You're trying to OutputTo a query, to the best of my knowledge that
   is not feasible.
2. Your file path is setup as `filepath\filename.xlsx` unless that is the actual location and name of your Excel sheet, something seems
   wrong there to me.
3. I don't really think this macro relates to an `ODBC` of any sort in its current state.

But, you should at least start with fixing the **filepath** issue. That should be the *full path* to your Excel file and the full name of the file as well. (i.e. `C:\TEMP\TestExcelSheet.xlsx`)

All that being said, you *may* want to just go with something like this (although its a little difficult to tell if this is what you actually want or not):

```
'Export Excel file from Query
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "acOutputQuery", _
"C:\TEMP\TestExcelSheet.xlsx", True
```

NOTE: `"acOutputQuery"` should be the *actual* name of your passthrough query, `"C:\TEMP\TestExcelSheet.xlsx"` would be your destination path, and `True` adds the query's headers into the sheet, `False` to ignore the headers.

Comment: I modified the code to what you suggested, but the only difference I can see is that the export had formatted column names.

My main problem is that when I run the macro, Access pops up a window to Select Data Source. I need to stop that from happening.